# lists/compound data

Tags: scheme, racket

how would you develop a function `one` that would consume a list of symbols and returns the same list but with every instance of `'cat` doubled?

so for example

```
 (one (cons 'animal(cons 'table (cons 'cat (cons 'bread
    empty)))))
```

I would get (I suppose)

```
 (cons 'animal (cons 'table (cons 'cat (cons 'cat (cons 'bread 
    empty)))))
```

in return.  I am getting frustrated reading the book and trying to figure this out.

Comment: The logical procedure to use would be `fold-left` or `fold-right` from SRFI1/R6RS.

Comment: BTW: `(cons 'animal(cons 'table (cons 'cat (cons 'bread empty))))` is simply written as `'(animal table cat bread)`

Comment: @leppie Not strictly the same if you want to use `set-car!` or `set-cdr!`. :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the simplest examples of how to recursively traverse a list while building another list. You should write it yourself, because you're in the process of learning. I'll help you a bit with the general structure of the solution, fill in the blanks:

```
(define (copy lst)
  (if <???>                 ; is the list empty?
      <???>                 ; if so, return the empty list
      (cons <???>           ; otherwise `cons` the first element of the list (*)
            (copy <???>)))) ; and advance the recursion over the rest of the list
```

(*) ... but if the element is `'cat`, then cons *two* copies of it.

Test it with the list in the question:

```
(copy (cons 'one (cons 'animal (cons 'table (cons 'cat (cons 'bread empty))))))
```

... Which happens to be equivalent to this:

```
(copy '(one animal table cat bread))
```

Either way, the result is a copy of the input list with the same elements (and two copies of each `'cat` found), but residing inside new cons-cells.

Answer (score 2):

Leppie (who told me to "go play with your mutation in the traffic ;p" in response to my `set-car!`/`set-cdr!` comment above ;-)) wanted me to write a fold-based solution, so here it is!

```
(define (fun lst)
  (fold-right (lambda (e r)
                (case e
                 ((cat) (cons* e e r))
                 (else (cons e r))))
              '() lst))
```